# How can I include a cache on my website?

Tags: performance, web

I want to make the performance of my own website a bit better.
So I want to implement a cache on my website.

Do you have any tutorials how I can do this?

[This is my page.](http://kaeptn-noize.com/)

Comment: what technology you used in your wesite

Comment: HTML, CSS, less and JavaScript.

Comment: First of all optimise it based on [PageSpeed](http://kaeptn-noize.com/) recommendations. You can think as well about some CDN solution if the problem is with your hosting performance. Besides there is already few free online solution that will analyze your site and give you some hints eg: [GTmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/kaeptn-noize.com/ifgExBCn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to these sites and take idea from them http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp
http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-http-caching/

Comment: Thank you very much!

I think this will help me a lot. :)